# Change number of executors impact

Tags: jenkins

What is the impact on the running jobs if I change the number of executors in the production environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on hardware used for master/slaves as well as on how much resource-intensive are your jobs.
We set the executors on our master to 0 and to our slaves - one executor per core.
Higher number of executors can result in degraded performance and higher flakiness of the jobs, especially true if they depend/share some data/application (database).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, valuable Information